# parsing bookmark.html in node.js

Tags: node.js, parsing, bookmarklet, bookmarks

i searched some nodejs module, in which and used netscape-bookmarks for creating bookmarks, now i want to read the bookmark.html file which i have created or imported from chrome browser.
i tried the code of 'npm-bookmark-parser' module but in that i am stuck to pass the file path which is stored in public folder of my project.
so how to parse bookmark file or is there any other easy module for that.

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: var grunt, parser;

grunt = require("grunt");
parser = require("../index");
var rr=  parser(path+filename, function(results) {
    console.log("results "+results);
    
  });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this module workd for me, can b helpful for other dev
https://gist.github.com/Sennahoi/e250ad6714bbdd7f2d7f

Comment: Perfect, so simple. I'm not going to elaborate on all the code contortions I went through trying to do that.